# Netgear Switch: equivalent for Cisco "Link State Tracking"/HP "Smartlink"

Tags: networking, switch, netgear

Cisco Switches implement a system called "Link State Tracking" - one uplink port can be defined, and mutliple downlink ports can be defined that use the uplink port. If the uplink port goes down (failure in the next switch, faulty cable...) the downlink ports will also be disabled. HP calls this feature "Smartlink".

We are using a Netgear M7100-24x switch in our virtual environment, and for redundancy purposes, this feature would be perfect for our needs.

So the quenstion is: does Netgear use something similar, and if so, what do they call it?

EDIT: Since no one knows a feature like this, a started a thread in the netgear community - maybe they know how to realise this or maybe i can make it a feature request somewhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Netgear Community would have been the quick and easy way to solve this...

The feature exists and is called "**Link Dependency**" - as far as i understood it is only implemented in the M4200 and M4300 switches, and not in the one that i have.